# angular8 proxy being directed to localhost:4200

Tags: proxy, angular8

I have configured a proxy for api calls to a serve in localhost:5000.
However, the proxy is being directed to localhost:4200 .i.e the angular application.
"Http failure response for http://localhost:4200/api/: 404 Not Found"

my proxy.conf.json:

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "https://127.0.0.1:5000/",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

my call to the url in a service :

```
private apiurl = "/api";
   constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
   getData() {
      return this.http.get(this.apiurl);
   }
```

I have edited 'start' in package.json

```
"start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
```

I am not getting any compiling errors.

I want /api to go to the target provided in the proxy conf file

Answer (score 0):

I am extremely sorry for this question, the issue was in my backend routing